# return boolean on done using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a container method for an `ajax` request:

```
function postRating(formData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/ratings',
        data: formData
    })
        .done(function () {
            return true
        })
        .fail(function () {
            return false
        })
        .always(function (msg) {
            //console.log(msg);
        });
}
```

which is called like so:

```
$('.episode-rating.like').click(function () {
    var formData = $("#episode-rating").serializeArray();
    formData.push({name: 'up', value: 1}, {name: 'down', value: 0});
    console.log(postRating(formData))
});
```

However `postRating()` returns `undefined`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I want to do some html processing if the ajax request is successfull and show an error otherwise.

Comment: Since it is a kind of asynchronous call!!

Comment: Ah so that means when `postRating()` is called it won't wait for a callback?

Comment: Yes it wont wait. It will be executed immediately and it would return the default return value `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is async, as mentioned above, so use callback:

```
function postRating(formData, cb) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/ratings',
        data: formData
    })
        .done(function () {
            cb(true);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            cb(false);
        })
        .always(function (msg) {
            //console.log(msg);
        });
}
```

And then:

```
postRating(formData, function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

Or you can use promises:

```
function postRating(formData, cb) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/ratings',
        data: formData
    });
}
```

and then:

```
postRating(formData)
   .done(function(){
        console.log(true);
    })
   .fail(function(){
        console.log(false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an async call. If you want you can make your ajax call sync and then you can return from the container, otherwise you would have to implement callbacks on the container, which are invoked upon success, error and complete.

```
// Async = false
function postRating(formData) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/ratings',
        data: formData,
        async: false
    });
}

// Callbacks
function postRating(formData, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/ratings',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            successCallback.apply(this, [data]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @Ortix92 I added an example.

Comment: But you should think twice before using `async: false`. It is not a good practice.